# I can not iterate over Python-docx document in word file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

[LOOK AT THE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSX30.png)I have the following code that reads a word docx document and write a line on the top of the table in it. It iterates over the tables inside the document. This is the old version of the code. I want to iterate over all the elements (supposely paragraphs and tables together) and insert two pointer (one for paragraphs and one for tables) and iterate with pointers. I want to write something before the previous paragraph where the data came from every table. If we have 3 tables, I want to write a sentence for every table before the last seen paragraph while we traverse the all the word file.

```
import docx
import section as section
from docx import Document
from docx.section import _Header
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
import re


# Insert a empty line before the tables in the document.
def insert_paragraph_before(item, text, style=None):
    """
    Return a newly created paragraph, inserted directly before this
    item (Table, etc.).
    """
    # CT_P.add_p_before(item._element)
    p = CT_P.add_p_before(item._element)
    # CT_P.add_p_before(item._element)
    p2 = Paragraph(p, item._parent)
    p2.text = text
    p2.style = styles["REQ"]
    return p2


FileName = 'Test'
document = docx.Document(FileName + ".docx")

styles = document.styles
style = styles.add_style('REQ', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)

# for table in document.tables:
# #     insert_paragraph_before(table, "" )

for table in document.tables:
    req_name = ""
    req_id = ""
    req_id_found = False
    counter = 0



    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                syntax = re.compile(r'(UNIT_S-REQ|UNIT_S-DC|UNIT_S-DD|Information|MRS-REQ|MRS-DC|MRS-DD)')
                result = syntax.findall(paragraph.text)

                if result and req_id_found == False:
                    req_id = table.cell(0, 1).text
                    # req_id = str(result[0])
                    req_id_found = True

                    txt = table.cell(2, 1).text
                    # print(txt)
                    if txt not in ["<name>"]:
                        req_name = table.cell(2, 1).text
                for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                    if req_id_found == True:
                        if counter != 0:
                            continue
                        if counter == 0:
                            if req_id and req_name:
                                document.add_heading(table, "ID-" + req_id + " - " + req_name)
                                print(table, "ID-" + req_id + " - " + req_name)
                                print(paragraph.text)
                            elif req_id and not req_name:
                                document.add_heading(table, "ID-" + req_id)
                                print(table, "ID-" + req_id)
                                print(paragraph.text)
                counter += 1

    if counter == 0:
        continue
    if counter != 0:
        if req_id and req_name:
            document.add_paragraph(table, "ID-" + req_id + " - " + req_name)
            print(table, "ID-" + req_id + " - " + req_name)
            print(paragraph.text)
        elif req_id and not req_name:
            document.add_paragraph(table, "ID-" + req_id)
            print(table, "ID-" + req_id)
            print(paragraph.text)
        counter += 1
document.save(FileName + "_modified.docx")
```

Comment: You must explain what problems you are facing and what is working correctly for you in the shared code.

Comment: I have a word document. There are the paragraphs and there are also tables under these paragraphs. These paragraphs explain the tables. I mean, each paragraphs have a tables. This code writes the information it gets from the tables as a title to the tables. I want to write these titles above the paragraphs.

Comment: I drew what is my problem. You can see from above.